# Python Spyder 5.0.0 "Reloaded modules" error

Tags: python, spyder

How can I sort out the following "red" prompt with a memo **Reloaded modules** (in Python Spyder 5.0.0)?

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I have two questions for you to see if we can fix this problem: 1) Are you using our Windows installer?; and 2) If that's the case, in what directory did you install Spyder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spyder 5.0.0 go to:

Tools>Preferences>Python Interpreter>(**untick**) Enable UMR

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not the Spyder 5 interface. Please go to the menu `Help > About Spyder` to get the actual Spyder version.